# OpenGL texture renders with very low quality

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

Due to performance bottlenecks in Core Graphics, I'm trying to use OpenGL EL on iOS to draw a 2D scene, but OpenGL is rendering my images at an incredibly low resolution.

Here's part of the image I'm using (in Xcode):

[image]

And OpenGL's texture rendering (in simulator):

[image]

I'm using Apple's Texture2D to create a texture from a PNG, and then to draw it to the screen. I'm using an Ortho projection to look straight down on the scene as was recommended in Apress' Beginning iPhone Development book. The image happens to be the exact size of the screen and is drawn as such (I didn't take the full image in the screenshots above). I'm not using any transforms on the model, so drawing the image should cause no sub-pixel rendering.

I'm happy to post code examples, but thought I'd start without in the case that there's a simple explanation.

Why would the image lose so much quality using this method? Am I missing a step in my environment setup? I briefly read about textures performing better as sizes of powers of two -- does this matter on the iPhone? I also read about multisampling, but I wasn't sure if that was related.

Edit: Updated screen shots so as to alleviate confusion.

Comment: do you use mip-mapping? edit: looks like the texture is just cut, so that can mean you are using texture coords that doesnt make the whole texture rendered on that quad, so it looks "zoomed in" like in your image it is. is that a real screenshot or just made manually? it looks really weird... cant think of how such rendering is possible. maybe try with a clear 256x256 texture and show the results?

Comment: I was afraid that my screenshots would be confusing. They're just manual screenshots. My image is drawn on the screen in a rect that is the exact size of the image, so yes, the whole texture should be rendered.

Comment: What is the image width/height ? you should always use power of two textures no matter what. You could start by showing the texture coordinates you are using, and the vertex coordinates too. Also show the whole texture just in case, and use some clear texture for it (not a sand texture etc where hard to see edges).

Comment: I noticed that your texture appears to not be a power of two - that can seriously screw with your OpenGL, especially on iOS with its much more limited implementation.

Comment: My real goal is to just display a 2D image on the screen. I'm not really trying to draw some object with various textures, but as I understand it, textures are the only way to accomplish this. I don't know much about mip-mapping, but I'm assuming it's not needed when I plan to render the image at full size. Still, I can try increasing the size of my image to be a power-of-two to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't fully understand why I was having quality issues with my code, but I managed to work around the problem. I was originally using the OpenGLES2DView class provided by the makers of the Apress book "Beginning iPhone 4 Development", and I suspect the problem lied somewhere within this code. I then came across [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1) which suggested I use GLKit instead. GLKit allowed me to do exactly what I wanted!

A few lessons learned:

1. Using GLKit and the sprites class in the tutorial linked above, my textures don't need to be powers of two. GLKit seems to handle this fine.
2. Multisampling was not the solution to the problem. With GLKit, using multisampling seemingly has no effect (to my eye) when rendering 2D graphics.

Thanks all who tried to help.

Comment: Did you try with power of two textures with the non-GLKit system? and how did that work? textures must always be power of two, i think GLKit just uses some texture atlas internally, so it just hides that issue from you.

Comment: I did try it with my non-GLKit system, and it didn't seem to make a difference in the quality. The problem almost certainly lied elsewhere in my code.